# A popUp keyboard appears in the bottom of the screen, I want a keyboard to appear related to each type of UITExtfield

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, first-responder

Basically i want when the user press the phone number to popup the number keyboard and i set this in Storyboard same for the Name with a normal keyboard and the date picker will popup when the user wants to enter the date.

Yet what i get is this little popup in the bottom of my screen for the three fields.
what did i do wrong ???
Only the date picker pop up works fine the other two fields give this picture in the bottom

[image: In the bottom of the screen there is a popup that holds the placeholder value with a done Button and this is not what i want w]

My ViewdidLoad

```
class SignUp : BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        renderButton()
        fullName.delegate = self
        birthDate.delegate = self
        phoneNumber.delegate = self
    }
```

My DatePicker for the date textfield

```
@objc func datePickerValueChanged(sender : UIDatePicker) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    birthDate.text! = formatter.string(from: sender.date).formattedDate!
}
```

And the extensions of the UITEXTFIELD

```
extension SignUp : UITextFieldDelegate {

    func  textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == birthDate {
            textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.topaz.cgColor


        } else if textField == fullName {
            textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.topaz.cgColor
        } else if textField == phoneNumber {
            textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.topaz.cgColor
        }
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField : UITextField) {
        if textField == birthDate {
            textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        } else if textField == fullName {
            textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        } else if textField == phoneNumber {
            textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        }
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: You are running in a simulator that's why. goto simulator --> I/O --> Keyboard --> Connect Hardware keyboard, Command + Shift + K will also work

Comment: Amazing that was really smooth in solving this issue thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in simulator go to Hardware > Keyboard > Toggle Software Keyboard, or you can use short cut